# General expression for non-independent gaussians

Tags: normal-distribution

I have a signal X of a single value which goes through K circuits (k=1 to k=K). Each circuit adds some noise with a normal distribution with ($\mu_{k}
 $ $\sigma_{k}$) and each circuit is indepedant of each other of its own normal distribution.

I need a general expression that tells me the output of the signal Y. Is this suppose to be the expression?

$g(x,\mu_{k},\sigma_{k})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^{2}}}e^{-{\displaystyle {\frac{(x-\mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}}}}}$

$Y=X+\Sigma_{k=1}^{K}\left(g(x,\mu_{k},\sigma_{k})\right)$

Can that summation of gaussians with independant mu and sigma be simplified? If so, is it possible to compute an expression for the MAP of X?

---

TLDR: Even a simple example would help me.

If I have X which follows a gaussian distribution, and K which follows a gaussian distribution. What is the MAP of X given Y and K?

Answer (score 0):

Your expression of $Y$ is not correct; you can not add probability density functions to random variables. The right choice, according to your description, should be
$$Y = X + \sum_{i = 1}^K Z_i,$$
where $Z_i$'s are **i.i.d.** Gaussian random variables independent of $X$, with $Z_i \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_k, \sigma_k^2)$.

Let $ Z = \sum_{i = 1}^K Z_i$, then $Z$ is also a Gaussian random variable. What you need to do is to calculate the posterior probability $p_{X|Y}(x|y)$.

Comment: aren't they indepedant gaussians? My expression does say that, since the k is varying. Also, does that mean that your variable Z is also a gaussian random variable with a mean and variance?

Comment: Is this correct?

$Z=\sum_{i=1}^{K}Z_{i}\: where\: Z_{i}\sim\mathcal{N}(\mu_{k},\sigma_{k}^{2})$
 
--------------
$P(X|Y)=\frac{P(Y|X)*P(X)}{P(Y)}$
 
---------------
$P(X|Y)=\frac{(X+\sum_{i=1}^{K}Z_{i})*\left(g(X,\mu_{x},\sigma_{x})\right)}{P(Y)}$
 
--------------
$\frac{d}{dX}\left(P(X|Y)\right)=\frac{d}{dX}\left((X+\sum_{i=1}^{K}Z_{i})*\left(g(X,\mu_{x},\sigma_{x})\right)\right)$